# Soft Credit report redirect to Contribution Detail report doesn't filter contact id

Tags: civireport, issues

It looks like the names in the Soft Credit report no longer redirect to a Contribution Detail report that filters the results based on the contact's id. This lack of filter is verified on the demo site. https://civicrm.demo.civihosting.com/civicrm  We are currently using Civi 5.0.0 and Drupal 7.59  What's the best way to address this issue?  Is this issues fixed in Civi 5.1?

[image]

Comment: Can you pls test this at dmaster.demo.civicrm.org which will always have the latest code on it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Yes, the same error occurs on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org.

Comment: The best way is to report the issue at lab.civicrm.org and if you are a developer you could fix it after reporting it.